# C code to open web browser

Tags: c, browser

What are some possible ways if any to execute a web browser on someone else's computer? I have a server and now when I use Process.Start. When someone executes that code from another computer the browser will show up on the server only.

What are some ways to have the browser open in their computer instead?

Comment: So you want to open a browser on a computer when they run a program?

Comment: yeah, well they connect to my server through a client. So if I used process start it will launch a browser on my vps, instead of their own computer =/

Comment: Well if the app is processing on the server it will open a browser on the server! You can't affect a computer from another computer.

Comment: would you know of any other ways to get this to work?

Comment: You need a way to tell **the client** to open a browser. What is the client exactly?

Comment: it's a game client, so I was just seeing any ways possible to say @firefox when the user types it in the game, and it will launch firefox browser on their pc

Comment: If you have the source to this client, you shouldn't need to go to the server at all. If I understand you correctly, when the user types `@firefox` in their client you can just run the code to open the browser on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect you're asking how to execute code remotely. This is done by using some form of [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). There are many RPC frameworks out there, so no definite answer can be given. Pick an RPC framework suitable for your situation and them you could ask a more specific question pertaining to that particular framework.

If, on the other hand, you're asking how to execute code on a client who just visits your web server, then no, that's not possible. And it's that way intentionally. Imagine the security implications if random websites would be able to run programs on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have your game client open a browser.  From the way it sounds, the server should never really be aware of any of this.